# `UIPageControll` бесконечный скролинг

Tags: ios, objective-c

Имеется `UIScrollView` со скроллингом по ширине

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width*array.count, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)]; // задаем количество слайдов,
```

к нему подвязанны три `UIView` переход между ними осуществляется через `UIPageControl` через метод делегата

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat pageWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds);
    CGFloat pageFraction = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x / pageWidth;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = roundf(pageFraction);
}
```

Все работает, проблема заключается в том, что мне нужен бесконечный скролинг. Например, с последнего скролла переходить на первый, а с первого на последний. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: если у вас есть например 3 страницы 1-2-3. вам надо сделать 5 страниц 3-1-2-3-1, и когда скролл доходит до конца с одной из сторон в методе didScroll его без анимации передвигать на другое положение того же элемента (с 1 на 4, с 5 на 2)

Comment: даже не так, сделать 3 страницы, начинать со второй, после скролла переставлять элементы местами и опять показывать вторую страницу. например начинаете вы в положении 3-1-2 со скроллом на странице номер 1, если произошел скролл направо, переставляете 1-2-3 и ставите контент оффсет на страницу 2

Comment: Спасибо, интересная идея, попробую.

Comment: Для решения использовал эту библиотеку, GBInfiniteScrollView. Все очень просто, без танцев с бубном.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую эту библиотеку потетить.

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не использовать UICollectionView с элементами располагающимися слева, там рекурсия объектов есть даже по умолчанию, если мне не изменяет память. Это будет выглядеть красивее и занимать меньше ресурсов.

Answer (score 0):

Скрол должен быть установлен на среднем элементе (и нужно включить paging).
Когда скрол закончит скролится (метод делегата scrollViewDidEndDecelerating)ты:
 - ставишь текущую вью (первую или третью) на второе место
 - вторую вьюшку на освободившееся место
 - скролл прокручиваешь на вторую вью (центральную). Без анимации
 - заполняешь вьюшки новыми данными